# Why is .mat files in matlab less than the actual variable in size?

Tags: matlab

I feel that my question isn't clear. I will explain that.

`im = dicomread('image.dcm');`

`whos im`
`Name        Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes`

`im        2294x1914            8781432  uint16`

notice that `im` reserved 8,781,432  bytes in memory.

On the other side, if I executed the next line.

`save('im.mat','im');`

`im.mat` will reserve 6,245,906 bytes in memory

the question is why is that? Are matlab compressing before saving .mat files?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. The [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html#br_4ten) says that:

> Beginning with Version 7, MATLAB compresses data when writing to MAT-files to save storage space.

I guess your MATLAB version is 7 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Matlab compresses .mat files.

Here is an explanation about it: http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-PM5NN/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-PM5NN